# Mouse moves by itself

Tags: 14.04, mouse, mousepad

My mouse moves by itself I cannot use the track-pad as the mouse jumps up and down the screen and also clicks by itself. When I boot into Windows, the track-pad works flawlessly so I suppose it's a problem on Ubuntu.

Luckily my laptop has a touch-screen so that is my current work-around.

`uname -a` information:

```
Linux Ubuntu 3.16.0-46-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 16:27:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is this a windows issue or ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu... I was just saying it works perfectly when i boot into windows so it is obviously a software problem.

Comment: Try to place the mouse above a cloth.

Comment: Do you mean the graphical cursor jumps around on your screen but you only have a track-pad and no actual mouse attached to the system?  If yes, please [edit] your question to reflect that critical info and also add the output to `synclient -l`. Then leave a comment @Fabby.  If it is your actual mouse itself jumping around, try with another one and see whether that has the same effect and provide the hardware make/model of the jumpy one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.